# extract elements of tuple from a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have a pandas series with data of type tuple as list elements. The length of the tuple is exactly 2 and there are a bunch of `NaNs`. I am trying to split each list in the tuple into its own column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [([1,2,3],[4,5,6]),
                           ([7,8,9],[10,11,12]),
                           np.nan]
                 })
```

Expected Output:

[image: eo]

Answer (score 2):

If you know the lenght of tuples are exactly 2, you can do:

```py
df["x"] = df.val.str[0]
df["y"] = df.val.str[1]
print(df[["x", "y"]])
```

Prints:

```
           x             y
0  [1, 2, 3]     [4, 5, 6]
1  [7, 8, 9]  [10, 11, 12]
2        NaN           NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also convert the column to a list and cast it to the DataFrame constructor (fill None with np.nan as well):

```
out = pd.DataFrame(df['val'].tolist(), columns=['x','y']).fillna(np.nan)
```

Output:

```
           x             y
0  [1, 2, 3]     [4, 5, 6]
1  [7, 8, 9]  [10, 11, 12]
2        NaN           NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `pandas.Series.apply`:

```
new_df = df["val"].apply(pd.Series)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
           0             1
0  [1, 2, 3]     [4, 5, 6]
1  [7, 8, 9]  [10, 11, 12]
2        NaN           NaN
```